# Linq to SQL Connection String for Sql Auth

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, connection-string

tI'm using Sql Server with Windows Authentication enabled. Recently I added a dropdown to allow for different connections. One of them uses SQL Authentication.

I consulted msdn and it seems all I need to do is add a Username and Password entry to my string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905872(v=sql.80).aspx

My windows authentication string :

```
Data Source=PC\Slike;Initial Catalog=db_slike_articles;Integrated Security=True
```

The second string I added for SQL Authentication :

```
Data Source=Data Source=PC\Dev;Initial Catalog=db_dev_articles;Integrated Security=True;User ID=root;Password=rootpwd
```

For some reason when I choose the 2nd SQL connection it's throwing an SqlException that login failed with my PC\Slike username. The connection string is the second one with the User ID and Pwd, I don't understand why it's trying to connect against my local account.

The second string is located on a remote machine, is there something I have to enable to switch from Windows Auth to Sql Auth or does specifying the the credentials within the string is enough?

Thanks

Comment: The SQL Authentication connection string still has `Integrated Security=True` in there, so Windows Auth is probably still going to be used. You should perhaps remove it to see if that changes things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using **SQL Authentication**, remove this from the connection string:

```
Integrated Security=True;
```

there is a web site listing all possible/supported syntax of connection strings for all database engines, I can't find it now, connectionstrings.com does not load properly.

Comment: You are totally right, I just saw Use the Integrated Security keyword, set to a value of SSPI, to specify Windows Authentication (recommended) in the page I linked. I think it's time to call it a day. Thanks!